# Make Chrome's omni bar search past URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying a switch from Safari to Chrome, and one of the biggest features I miss from Safari is the ability to search historical URLs from the address/omni bar. For example, I've recently (and frequently) visited a URL which contains `File.html`, but Chrome doesn't show it in the omni bar:

[image: chrome's omni bar]

Is there any way (extension, setting, etc) to trick Chrome into searching historical URLs from the omni bar?

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't an answer, but I've NEVER had any trouble with it. Just works.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you go to  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html — does it show up in your omni bar after that?

Comment: To clarify, I do sort of get something like that for some things (eg, https://img.skitch.com/20110720-knhgs3ia3nr3wj2uassaiy3fgg.png ), but it's not very consistent (ex, https://img.skitch.com/20110720-m2e97utpxe223hi7mpw6b1mak7.png ) and it often doesn't show me what I want (ex, the `File.html` example in my original post).

Comment: http://twitpic.com/5svo6q just not seeing what's missing. Perhaps its your workflow. I find chromes omnibar refreshingly accurate and useful.

Comment: Not at all like their rubbish search in gmail :D

Comment: Hhmm… Possibly. It looks like typing the *domain* is the key… Although I guess you're still out of luck if you need to type more than just the domain to find what you want.